# Content items do not reload when new data arrives?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am currently working on the backend of my electron software with a python program that continuously sends random data to the javascript program and to the react variables (React library) via Flask. But the element that receives the data does not reload automatically. I have to reload the page to display new data because as soon as I reload the page, it calls the getdata() function of my python program. I would like to know how to insert the data so that the elements update automatically with the display?

Here is my JS and python code :

**main.js** :

```
const { BrowserWindow, app, ipcMain, Notification } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const isDev = !app.isPackaged;

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

if (isDev) {
  require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
    electron: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

**App.js** :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/data");
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
    };
    // Exécute la fonction toutes les secondes
    const intervalId = setInterval(fetchData, 1000);
    // Nettoie l'intervalle lorsque le composant est démonté
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);
  return (
    <div>
            <div class="home">
                <div class="template-1" id="temp1">
                <div class="panel-1">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1>Panel 1</h1>
                    <i class='bx bx-cog modal-trigger-panel'></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="sec-5 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-5">
                        <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{this.state.data[0]}</span>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s5</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-4 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-4">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s4</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-3 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-3">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-2 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-2">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s2</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-1 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-1">
                        <h1>--</h1>
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s1</h3>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}
```

**Python** :

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/data')
def get_data():
  data = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)]
  return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Regards,